# checking if list of dictionary has a dictionary containing specified value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am trying to check if a list of dictionaries contains a key with a specified value
if it does contain a dictionary with this value I want to target this dictionary and if it doesn't I want to create the dictionary

here is what my list of dictionaries looks like

```
my_list = [
   {"name": "home", "content": "home"}, {"name": "contact", "content": "contact"}
]
```

I want to check if `my_list` has a dictionary with a key `"name"` and a value of as an example `"events"` which does not exist so I would need to add it to my list and if it did I would want to modify the dictionaries key `"content"`

```
if {"name": "events"} in my_list:
   list_found = my_list[index_of_the_dictonary]
else:
   my_list.append({
      "name": "events"
      "content": []
   })
```

Comment: your code is faulty - missing `,`

Comment: you exmple list does not contain a dict that only contains `{"name": "content"}` so the `in`-operator  won't work - kit checks if this exact dict is inside the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `else` to `for` loop to solve the problem:

```
my_list = [
   {"name": "home", "content": "home"},
   {"name": "contact", "content": "contact"}
]

for x in my_list:
    if x.get('name') == 'events':
        print('Dictionary Found')
        break
else:
    my_list.append({'name': 'events', 'content': []})

print(my_list)
# [{'name': 'home', 'content': 'home'}, {'name': 'contact', 'content': 'contact'}, {'name': 'events', 'content': []}]
```

An `else` to `for` loop is executed only when the `for` loop is executed normally to its completion i.e. without `break`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for d in my_list:
    if d.get('name') == 'events':
        list_found = d # d is the dictonary you expected
        break
else:    
    my_list.append({"name":"events", "content": []}) # Create it
```